# Breezejs entity save failing because json data is too large

Tags: json, iis, asp.net-web-api, breeze, hottowel

Breeze seems to be creating a very large file considering the object model I am passing it to save.

I am only saving one instance of a drug with 1 Drug option with 1 available route and some text fields with a single word in each.

When I grab the bundle from debug.breeze.js from line 14705 and save it to a text file the file is 35+ mb. This seems like an aweful lot of data for this straight forward object model.

Is there any way to slim down the json with just the objects? So I don't have to alter the IIS settings?

****************** Link to exported json that breeze is sending to the server ***********

[Sample of json that's causing the problem](http://1drv.ms/1mRhSai)

****************Here is a screen shot of the graph *************

[image: Entire Graph]

[image: Drug Graph Item]

[image: Solid Option Graph Item]

[image: Available Solid Route]

my datacontext.saveChanges code......

```
       function saveDictionaryChanges(entity) {
            var graph = manager.getEntityGraph(entity,  'drugIndications, ' +
                  'drugOptions, ' +
                  'drugOptions.concentrations, ' +
                  'drugOptions.availableRoutes, ' +
                  'drugOptions.availableDrugForms, ' +
                  'drugOptions.availableUnits');

        // Filter for changes only  
        graph = graph.filter(function (entity) {
            return entity.entityAspect.entityState.isAddedModifiedOrDeleted();
        });

        return manager.saveChanges(graph)
            .then(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);


        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            //TODO: Commented out because WIP is on the back burner
            //zStorage.save();


            logSuccess('Saved Data', result, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Save failed: ' +
                breeze.saveErrorMessageService.getErrorMessage(error);
            error.message = msg;

            logError(msg, error);
            throw error;

        }

    }
```

my object model is

There are 4 other inherited available route types liquid,inhalation,injectable and topical. I only included AvailableSolidRoutes to help shorten he question.

```
     public class AvailableRoute {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DrugOptionId { get; set; }
        public int RouteId { get; set; }
       public virtual Route Route { get; set; }
     }

    public class AvailableSolidRoute : AvailableRoute {
       public AvailableSolidRoute( ) { }
    }
```

There is also a Inhalation,Injectable & topical concentration object that inherit from concentration. I've only include LiquidConcentration to help shorten the question.

```
   public abstract class Concentration {        
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public int DrugOptionId { get; set; }
          public DrugOption DrugOption { get; set; }
          public decimal Measure{ get; set; }
          public int MassUnitId { get; set; }
          public virtual Unit MassUnit { get; set; }
          public int VolumeUnitId { get; set; }
          public virtual Unit VolumeUnit { get; set; }
          public int? DrugFormId { get; set; }
          public virtual DrugForm DrugForm { get; set; }        
          public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }             
   }

   public class LiquidConcentration : Concentration {
      public LiquidConcentration( ) {}
   }
```

There 4 other inherited types like solid option Liquid,Inhalation,Injectable & Topical

```
   public class DrugOption {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public int DrugId { get; set; }
         public Drug Drug { get; set; }  

         public List<AvailableDrugForm> AvailableDrugForms { get; set; }
         public List<AvailableRoute> AvailableRoutes{ get; set; }
         public List<AvailableUnit> AvailableUnits { get; set; }
         public List<Concentration> Concentrations { get; set; }
         public string SpecialInstructions { get; set; }
   }

   public class SolidOption : DrugOption  {
         public SolidOption( ) { }
   }
```

Drug is the root class that all the previous classes relate to:

```
   public class Drug {
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public string Name { get; set; }
          public string Alias{ get; set; }
          public string Directions { get; set; }
          public bool DirectionsIsEditable { get; set; }
          public string SpecialDirections { get; set; }
          public bool SpecialDirectionsIsEditable { get; set; }
          public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
          public IList<DrugIndication> DrugIndications { get; set; }
          public IList<DrugOption> DrugOptions { get; set; }

         public Drug( ) { }
  }
```

Comment: 35+ mb for only one entity? Try to filter like this:  `return entity.entityAspect.entityState !== breeze.EntityState.Unchanged` and check the size again

Comment: No it's for a Drug with 1 Drug Option with 1 Available Route.. the graph is filtered via   graph = graph.filter(function (entity) {
            return entity.entityAspect.entityState.isAddedModifiedOrDeleted();
        });

Comment: Tough to say unless I know what is actually in the save bundle. Don't give me the 35MB :-).  Just tell me what's there and which things are big. Because I can't imagine how you get so big if you really only have two or three entities represented in that bundle (the `graph` array has just 2 or 3 items before you save, right?)

Comment: Yup, its a drug,drugoption,availableroute... When I copied the json from the breeze library mentioned above and put it into a text file , saved it the file size is 35mb. I can put the file on one drive Monday am and post a link to it if u like?....

Comment: The problem maybe because drugoption has the list of available routes (1 in this case) and I also map availableroutes in the getEntityGraph...because it wont put the availableroutes in the graph to save otherwise.

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you are sweeping the graph array for changes-only. If you have more than 3 objects in the graph array after the sweep, the circumstances are not what you said/think they are.

Comment: Updated answer to show screen shots of the graph

Comment: Just to note saving a already created Drug Option works fine.. seems to only exhibit this behavior on new Drug Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***************** I fixed this issue (Was self induced hehe!) *************
So in order to make it easier to bind my "DrugOptions" to the UI. I created
clientside properties on the drug for each type of drug options.

I did not understand what this code was actually doing.. I added it thinking it would
remove the clientside property before sending entity changes to breeze. That is not it's purpose.

Rightly so breeze was confused about the clientside properties because it does not know about them.

```
        if (changedProp === 'solidOption') {
            delete changeArgs.entity.entityAspect.originalValues[changedProp];
        }
```

I moved these properties to the Controller and it's perfectly fine now :)